# cmis versions 1.0 or 1.1 documentum and alfresco jar files and stuff

Tags: opencmis

I have a question about the versions and version numbering convention around Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS and wondered if it could be clarified for me.

I was surprised

```
System.out.println(session.getRepositoryInfo().getCmisVersion() );
```

Told me EMC Documentum 7.0 and Alfresco ("current version" at time of writing) seem only to support

```
<cmis:cmisVersionSupported>1.0</cmis:cmisVersionSupported>
```

From the [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html)
download page (for which the latest version of CMIS is 1.1)
but version numbers for Chemistry show Release 0.10.0 (2013-08-15)

Can someone please explain to me how the version numbering works and what 0.10.0 is in relation to CMIS 1.1? 
It says at the top of the page

> Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS is a collection of Java libraries, frameworks and tools around the CMIS 1.0 and CMIS 1.1 specifications.

So am I correct in my understanding that these client libraries (which have the version 0.10.0) will support servers which are CMIS 1.1 compliant and this numbering convention is nothing to do with CMIS 1.0 or 1.1 compliance?

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Comment: As a general rule, the version number of a piece of software isn't related to the version number of any standards it implements, except when Marketing teams get involved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCMIS up to 0.8.0 supports CMIS 1.0. OpenCMIS 0.9.0 and later supports CMIS 1.0 and CMIS 1.1. The client library adapts automatically to the server.
The OpenCMIS version number has nothing to with the supported CMIS version.